# Debugging out of memory exception

Tags: exception, nhibernate, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, castle-windsor

I am investigating into a memory leak issue I am encountering in my application. There is large amount of System.String on GC heap (close to 3GB). On some investigation, i got to the following root references. Is it the problem with Windsor that is not releasing the components and keeping track of them ?

```
0:000> !gcroot 3dfc30b0
    HandleTable:
        21c512ec (pinned handle)
        -> 136e17d0 System.Object[]
        -> 02c4eacc Azure.Cloud.Util.IoC.IoC
        -> 02c4eac0 Azure.Cloud.Util.IoC.ResolveWindsorContainer
        -> 06bec338 Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer
        -> 06bec35c Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel
        -> 06bec464 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, Castle.Windsor]]
        -> 06becb64 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.ISubSystem, Castle.Windsor]][]
        -> 06becbe0 Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.DefaultDiagnosticsSubSystem
        -> 06becbf8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.IContainerDebuggerExtension, Castle.Windsor]]
        -> 06becdf8 System.Object[]
        -> 06bece5c Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.Extensions.ReleasePolicyTrackedObjects
        -> 06bece68 Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.TrackedComponentsDiagnostic
        -> 06becf4c System.EventHandler`1[[Castle.Windsor.Diagnostics.TrackedInstancesEventArgs, Castle.Windsor]]
        -> 06bece9c Castle.MicroKernel.Releasers.LifecycledComponentsReleasePolicy
        -> 06beceb4 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Object, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.Burden, Castle.Windsor]]
        -> d6463f60 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.Object, mscorlib],[Castle.MicroKernel.Burden, Castle.Windsor]][]
        -> 83727088 NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl
        -> 837273b4 NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext
        -> 83727408 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, NHibernate],[System.Object, mscorlib]]
        -> 83727470 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[NHibernate.Engine.EntityKey, NHibernate],[System.Object, mscorlib]][]
        -> 837282ec Azure.Cloud.Domain.Lists.ItemList
        -> 83728778 NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag`1[[Azure.Cloud.Domain.Lists.ItemListDetail, Azure.Cloud.Domain]]
        -> 8372c1b4 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, mscorlib]]
        -> 8372c1cc System.Object[]
        -> 8372bff4 Azure.Cloud.Domain.Lists.ItemListDetail
        -> 3dfc30b0 System.String
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember to tell Windsor to [release the objects](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/27/must-i-release-everything-when-using-windsor/). This can be done in a number of ways, as described by the article.